# Scipy stft, how is shape of f determined?

Tags: stft

Using scipy stft, like this :

```
sample_rate, samples = scipy.io.wavfile.read(sample_dir/'original'/test_sample_name)
f, t, Zxx = scipy.signal.stft(samples.transpose(), sample_rate)
```

`f.shape` is equal to 129. My understanding is that this number represents the number of frequency at which we evaluate the Fourier Transform. How is it calculated? Can we fix this number?

Comment: can you read the [scipy.signal.stft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html) documentation, where how to set is explained, and reformulate that question based on that knowlede?

Comment: A year late, but I found the size of `f` to be either equal to the hop size `H = nperseg - noverlap` or half the value of `nfft`. No idea why.